# Selector Priority and usage of "em"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm reading a book called "DOM Scripting-Web Design with javascript and the Document Object Model". In chapter 11, I saw a css file illustrated below.

```
body {
  font-size: 76%;
  font-family: "Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
}
body * {
  font-size: 1em;
}
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
}
#navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#content {
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
#content p {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",sans-serif;
  font: 2.4em normal;
}
h2 {
  font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",sans-serif;
  font: 1.8em normal;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
h3 {
  font-family: "Georgia","Times New Roman",sans-serif;
  font: 1.4em normal;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#imagegallery li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
dt {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
dd {
  margin-right: 3em;
}
textarea {
  font-family: "Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
}
```

Here I think "font-size:76%" in body part is useless because it will be covered by definition in body * part. So, why does the writer design a css like this?

Comment: Or if you also agree with my opinion that definition of text-font:76% is not needed, just say something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the font depends on both qualities.  For example, it is very evident here what the `em` adds to the percentage: http://jsfiddle.net/EQ3vF/1/

The result is a percentage of the full font-size.

Answer (score 2):

The `em` unit is measured based on the parent's font size.

In this case, the parent is (eventually) the body, which gets `76%` of the user's default font size.

Comment: Ok, thx! I'm a beginner and now I know the usage of "em". Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The rule `body * { font-size: 1em; }` does not affect the font size of the `body` element at all, since that element does not match the selector `body *` (which is matched by all descendants by the `body` element but not the `body` element itself).

So `font-size: 76%` on `body` surely has an effect here. Whether it is a good effect is a different issue. What it does is that it sets the document’s basic font size to 76% of the size that the user has selected (either by not changing browser defaults on font size or by setting them to some value). The usual reason to this oddity is that authors choose to use the Arial font and think that it is ugly in the common default font size.

This has nothing to do with selector priority. The selectors `body *` and `body` never apply to the same element, so no priority issue arises.

You mention the usage of `em` in the question title but not in the question body. Thus, it is difficult to say what is your question about it, but it simply means the font size of the element, *except* when used in the value of `font-size`, where it means the font size of the *parent* element. In particular, `body * { font-size: 1em; }` sets the font size of any descendant of the `body` element to the same as the font size of the `body` element itself. In practice, this overrides browser default settings for some elements like headings and `input` elements. But this setting itself can be overridden by an author’s other settings, like `font: 2.4em normal` for `h1` in this case (it is a shorthand that sets `font-size` to `2.4em` among other things).